# Kinect front light cause grip detection errors

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm writing an application that use kinect for windows (not the new full hd kinect) with sdk 1.8. I'm using kinect region and kinectScrollviewer. In front of the kinect camera there's a window, so the subject who must be tracked has the sun light source that comes from behind. When the light is intense, kinect loose the ability to detect correctly the grab and release interaction (sometimes the events of grab or release are fired randomly). My application will run in environments where this kind of lights conditions will be possible. My question is, there's some parameters in skeletal stream or something else that i can set to change the sensibility to this kind of light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kinect sensor works using infrared light, which the IR rays in the sun will disturb (you can see this in the depth map when you have direct sunlight, see this link: http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/KINECT_in_direct_sunlight), so unfortunately there isn't much you can do about it except trying to get rid of the sunlight.

Here is another video of how the depth sensing works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq9SEJxZiUg